# Trigger on Pricebook Entry or Finding whether a Product has a standard price

Tags: trigger, pricebookentry

I need to perform some action when a Standard price is added to a product. I need to capture when it happen, so SOQL won't help me here.
How can I trigger on new PricebookEntry or, is there a field on the Product that can tell me if the Product has a Standard price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XnicAAC, you can see that PricebookEntry does not allow triggers at the moment.

As far as I can see, your two options to mimic the triggering event are:

1. Use a continuously running job (can be <3 minutes per execution using 'suicide' scheduling, or possibly Queuable).  Because there's no history on PricebookEntry (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D9sAAAS), you'll need to stash current prices in a custom sObject and use SOQL to diff and detect changes per execution, then refresh your price stash.
2. Alternatively, you could try and overwrite the UI component in which you make manual changes to prices by using a visualforce page, and simultaneously kick off your price change event from the VF.

My opinion is neither of these options is much good, and the Success thread above's comments are right in that not treating repricing as an 'event' of any interest to the system is a critical deficiency.